# Setting nginx for yii 2

Tags: nginx, yii2, nginx-location

I try install yii2 to nginx.

Old settings:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        root /var/www/mp.test/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name mp.test www.mp.test;

        location /pma {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
        }
       }
}
```

And folder /var/www/mp.test/public_html/index.html

Now i install yii2 to folder public_html, and create new settings

```
server {
        listen   80;
        root /var/www/mp.test/public_html/web;
        index index.html;
        server_name mp.test www.mp.test;

        location /pma {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
        }
       }
}
```

And i got error 403. How I can setting server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is the official configuration check [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config)

```
    server {
    set $host_path "/www/mysite";
    access_log  /www/mysite/log/access.log  main;

    server_name  mysite;
    root   $host_path/htdocs;
    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
    }

    # prevent nginx from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```